# Ansible win_hotfix It shows as if the KB is installed but it is not

Tags: ansible, hotfix

I tried to install a KB using win_hotfix but it shows like the kb is already installed. When I check in the server if it is installed it is not.

```
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
ok: [SPPEAPP00140] => (item=2-kb5034127.msu) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "identifier": "Package_for_ServicingStack_5084~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.5084.1.2",
    "identifiers": [
        "Package_for_ServicingStack_5084~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.5084.1.2",
        "Multiple_Packages~~~~0.0.0.0"
    ],
    "item": "2-kb5034127.msu",
    "kb": "KB5034127",
    "kbs": [
        "KB5034127",
        "KB5034127"
    ],
    "reboot_required": false
}


EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
failed: [SPPEAPP00140] (item=item.kb) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "Get-HotFix | findstr \"KB5034127\"",
    "delta": "0:00:09.456481",
    "end": "2024-02-12 03:48:23.780640",
    "item": {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "identifier": "Package_for_ServicingStack_5084~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.5084.1.2",
        "identifiers": [
            "Package_for_ServicingStack_5084~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~17763.5084.1.2",
            "Multiple_Packages~~~~0.0.0.0"
        ],
        "item": "2-kb5034127.msu",
        "kb": "KB5034127",
        "kbs": [
            "KB5034127",
            "KB5034127"
        ],
        "reboot_required": false
 …
```

apparently this only happens on Windows Server 2019. Please your help in order to solve this issue.